# Find the value of $(a - b)^2$ given $a + b = 2$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$a + b = 2\\
> a^2 + b^2 = 6$$
>
> Find the value of $(a-b)^2 $

My workings till I got stuck -

$$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \\
= a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\\ 
= 6 - 2 ab $$

I'm stuck at how to find $ab$ . Can I get hints on how to find $ab$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $4= (a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

Comment: Squaring the first equation then subtract the second equation from it.

Comment: The above comments mean that you should consider the quantity $2a^2+2b^2-(a+b)^2$...

Answer (score 10):

Use
$$(a-b)^2+(a+b)^2=2(a^2+b^2)$$
Thus, here,
$$(a-b)^2+4=12$$
$$(a-b)^2=8$$

Answer (score 1):

We will solve for the values of $a$ and $b$. $a=2-b$ so $a^2+b^2=6 \iff (2-b)^2 + b^2 +6 $

This means $2b^2-4b-2=0 \iff b^2 -2b -1 +0 $. The solutions of this equation are $b=1-\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1+\sqrt{2}$. Then $a=1+\sqrt{2}$ or $a=1-\sqrt{2}$

Then, in any case $(a-b)^2=8$

Comment: -1.This is a low grade method.

Answer (score 1):

> $$a+b=2$$
>
> $$\implies(a+b)^2=4$$
>
> $$\implies a^2+b^2+2ab=4$$
>
> $$\implies2ab=-2$$

Also,

> $$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$$
>
> $$6-(-2)=6+2=8$$(by substituting $a^2+b^2=6$ and $2ab=-2$)